# Difficulty in reading the registers using the I2C

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal-library

It is necessary to obtain the values of angular velocity of the [gyroscope module](http://files.amperka.ru/datasheets/L3G4200D-hyroscope.pdf) on ["Amperka" board](http://wiki.amperka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B:troyka-imu-10-dof). But even to read the identifier register, returned incorrect answers. Already the day is spent and not have achieved even this, not to mention the angular ) I Use the HAL library. Here's my code:

```
    void Accel_Ini(void)
{
        uint16_t ctrl = 0x0000;
        HAL_Delay(500);
        if(Accel_ReadID()!=0x68) while(1);
        AccInit(ctrl);
}

uint8_t Accel_ReadID(void)
{
uint8_t ctrl = 0x00;
        ctrl = Accel_IO_Read(0x68,0x0F);
        return ctrl;
}

uint8_t Accel_IO_Read(uint16_t DeviceAddr, uint8_t RegisterAddr)
{
        return I2Cx_ReadData(DeviceAddr, RegisterAddr);
}

static uint8_t I2Cx_ReadData(uint16_t Addr, uint8_t Reg)
{

        HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;

        uint8_t value = 0;

        status = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, Addr, Reg, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &value, 1, 0x10000);

        if(status != HAL_OK)
                    while(1);

        return value;

}
```

[image]
(gyro adress is 0x68)

Comment: Are you on a PC with an I2C bridge between the PC and the Amperka (e.g. UART to I2C maybe?)?

Comment: @CapnJJ No, I2C between STM32 and the gyro

Comment: I don't understand... how do you interact with the STM32 to get the register values?  You load your SW on the STM32, and it is supposed to read the Gyro register (among other things), and how do you know what value is returned?  I was thinking you must have some terminal/PC to view the results(?)  i.e. Maybe the I2C between the STM32 and the gyro is ok, but the interface from which you get the data is not working properly?

Comment: @CapnJJ while debuging i look at my terminal)

Comment: Are you able to read other registers successfully?  Sorry to ask the obvious, and maybe you are way past this point, but, have you verified your link to your terminal is working properly in your setup (I assume it is a tty-UART)?  And, are your HAL library I2C functions configured to match the I2C with which you are interfacing?  e.g. Address 7-bit, versus 10-bit

Comment: @CapnJJ Yes, a do. All I2C and UART settings correctly. My problems with programming part(

Comment: You are reading from register 0x0f, which should return 0b1101001=0xd3. If-statement in line 5 checks for 0x68.

Comment: @M2C8 Why it should return 1101001? (And 0b1101001 = 0x69)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function 'Accel_ReadID()' returns the content of the register 0x0f of I2C-Slave with address 0x68.

In table 18 of the [datasheet](http://files.amperka.ru/datasheets/L3G4200D-hyroscope.pdf) (page 27) you can find the corresponding register description:

- Name: WHO_AM_I
- Address: 0x0f
- Default: 0b11010011 (=0xd3)

So you have to compare the return value with 0xd3 (the default register content) and not 0x68 (the slave's address).

The function Accel_Init() should therefore be changed as follows:

```
void Accel_Ini(void) {
    uint16_t ctrl = 0x0000;
    HAL_Delay(500);
    if(Accel_ReadID()!=0xd3) while(1);
    AccInit(ctrl);
}
```